# WordPress - How to add CSS style to all header menu buttons whilst excluding one

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm working on a site (using WordPress) and I want to add custom CSS to all of the menu page buttons except for one page button (Contact) which already has it's own, separate CSS styling.

The CSS adds a line that appears to grow from left to right directly beneath the menu item being hovered over. It will also set a static line directly beneath the active page link.

[Hover Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRDJM.gif)

I got this code from here: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/beautiful-css-hover-effects-you-can-add-to-your-divi-menus

So how can I add this to all of the menu buttons except the "Contact" button?

Here is the code below:

```
#top-menu .current-menu-item a::before,
#top-menu .current_page_item a::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#top-menu li a:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -2;
 left: 0;
 right: 100%;
 bottom: 50%;
 background: #15bf86; /*** COLOR OF THE LINE ***/
 height: 3px; /*** THICKNESS OF THE LINE ***/
 -webkit-transition-property: right;
 transition-property: right;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
 transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
#top-menu li a:hover {
 opacity: 1 !important;
}
#top-menu li a:hover:before {
 right: 0;
}
#top-menu li li a:before {
 bottom: 10%;
}
```

Would it be better to make this code for each specific button instead and not making one for the "Contact" button? If so how can I do so?

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle your case with [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) by:

1. adding a specificity to your *Contact* item (let's say the class `exclude-style`)
2. changing the CSS selectors you show so that each `a:***` becomes `a:not(.exclude-style):***`

Like this:

`#top-menu .current-menu-item a:not(.exclude-style)::before`

`#top-menu li a:not(.exclude-style):before`

`#top-menu li a:not(.exclude-style):hover`

`#top-menu li a:not(.exclude-style):hover:before`

`#top-menu li li a:not(.exclude-style):before`

Comment: Thanks, I actually got the answer from Divi themselves and the answer was the same as yours, but you broke it down more. Thanks again for your comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is find the default styles, so remove the rules above, until you have a style you want for the `Contact` button. Copy those styles, and place them into a rule with the selector of `#contact`, and put an ID attribute of `contact` on your `Contact` button like here: `<a href="contact.html" id="contact">Contact</a>` or whatever your `Contact` item is. Then use the following CSS:

```
#contact {
    /*Styles on the Contact button only, for example: */
    background-color: orange;
}
```

These styles will only be applied to the `Contact` button. You can put your styles for the other buttons back, only make sure to put them ***above*** the new `#contact` rule, so it overrides them and your page looks like you want it to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I spoke with Divi support which helped me out but I will keep your answer in mind in case a similar issue comes up again.